# CORS issue with AWS API Gateway

Tags: cors, aws-api-gateway

I am send post request from my web-page to AWS API Gateway which is invoking a lambda function. CORS is enabled in the API Gateway.

Error:

> Failed to load api_gatewau_url: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource. Origin
>   'url' is therefore not allowed access.

The resource is having two methods:

1. OPTIONS (integration MOCK)
2. POST (integration Lambda)

How to solve CORS issue?

Below is the code for sending post request.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    url: "api_gateway_url",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "param1": value1,
        "param2": value2
    }),
```

I have also tried to add headers with allow origin true etc but no luck.
Strangest thing, same configuration and request I am trying with different api gateway then it is working fine without any errors.

Comment: What is method integration of resource on your API Gateway?

Comment: the resource is having two methods: OPTIONS (integration MOCK) and and POST (integration Lambda)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your type of integration you need to return the COR's headers.

More detail can be found at,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#The_HTTP_response_headers

If you are using ANY integration, you can return the headers from your Lambda or other sources where you are integrating with.

For Lambda,

```
module.exports.hello = function(event, context, callback) {

    const response = {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "https://domain:port", // Required for CORS support to work
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true // Required for cookies, authorization headers with HTTPS
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ "message": "Hello World!" })
    };

    callback(null, response);
};
```

If you are using S3,

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-cors-configuration.html

**API Gateway CORS Mapping:**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your answer for Lambda is correct ONLY when it's Lambda proxy integration.

Comment: Just gave an example how the return headers should be.

Comment: You [can't use](https://www.moesif.com/blog/technical/cors/Authoritative-Guide-to-CORS-Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing-for-REST-APIs/#credentials-with-wildcard) `Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*` with `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials=true`.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using proxy integration in API Gateway, then enabling CORS from API Gateway doesn't work. You have to set the Header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' from your Lambda code itself.

Its mentioned in the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html#how-to-cors-console).

Python code sample:

```
    response = {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        'body': json.dumps({'message': 'CORS enabled')
    }
    return response
```

Comment: Indeed, this seems to be the only solution. But what if the lambda code does not get to execute due to error such as _Payload too large_. Then AWS returns a default response, with no headers :(

Answer (score 1):

If you're using lambda proxy you have to add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in your lambda

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
```

If not using lambda proxy you can go to API Gateway click on the actions drop down and select enable CORS to enable it.

[image]